# Mongoose validation only when changed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to validate a users email address, but only when it is changed. The following code seems to vlaidate everytime I make a save to any `Entrant`, and therefore is throwing an error that the email is a duplicate when it saves itself.

How do I properly validate when the Entrant is created rather than everytime I make an edit and save?

```
EntrantSchema.pre 'save', (next)->
  user = this  
  # Email Validation
  if (user.isModified('email'))
    console.log "Email has been changed".green.inverse

    # Unique Value
    EntrantSchema.path("email").validate ((email,respond) ->
      Entrant.findOne {email:email}, (err,user) ->
        if user
          respond(false)
        respond(true)
    ), "Oopsies! That e-mail’s already been registered"
```

Note that I think the validate() is being bound the first time, because when I update a user, I do not get "Email has been changed", which I'm console.logging in my code

Comment: Probably, it may be done with `this.isModifies('email')` ([see docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified)), but I'd recommend you to use [unique index](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique) instead.

Comment: I have isModified(), see the code above. I need to use my own validator for other reasons

Comment: FYI for other readers: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator Unique index shouldn't be used for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using validation the wrong way. Mongoose attach validators to the schema and not to the single document, which makes them global.

So, instead of validating email in `pre 'save'` you should define a good email validator:

```
EntrantSchema.path('email').validate ((email,respond) ->
  return respond true unless @isModified 'email'
  Entrant.count {email}, (err, count) ->
    respond count is 0
), "Oopsies! That e-mail’s already been registered"
```

But if you want email to be unique then it's best to use `unique` index instead:

```
EntrantSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  email: type: String, unique: true
```

Checking unique values in validators leaves the possibility to update two users with the same email.

By the way, hooks (`pre` and `post`) [will be removed in `Mongoose 4.0`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1446).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. It was the @isModifed that I was looking for inside of the validator. Thank you :)