# Get isModified in validator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to check if a path has been modified in a validator?  Do I need to check or do validators only run if the path was changed?

**EDIT:**

More specifically, I am trying to make sure an author exists before I insert an id:

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    authorId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
  });

BookSchema.path('authorId').validate(function(authorId, done) {
  Author.getAuthorById(authorId, function(err, author) {
    if (err || !author)  {
      done(false);
    } else {
      done(true);
    }
  });
}, 'Invalid author, does not exist');
```

In this case I only want this to validate if authorId is set or if it changes.  Do I need to check if changed in the function or can I assume that this validator only gets called if the authorId changes and is not null/undefined?

This makes it look like I might be able to call isModified, however I don't see that as a function on 'this'.
[Mongoose validation only when changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063297/mongoose-validation-only-when-changed/18063635#18063635)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, validators are only run if the path is changed, and they also only run if they're not `undefined`. Except the Required validator, which runs in both cases.